# How can you do projection with array_agg(order by)?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with three columns: `id`, `name` and `position`. I want to create a JSON array as following:

```
[
    {"id": 443, "name": "first"},
    {"id": 645, "name": "second"}
]
```

This should be listed by the `position` column.

I started with the following query:

```
with output as
(
    select id, name
    from   the_table
)
select array_to_json(array_agg(output))
from   output
```

This works, great. Now I want to add the ordering. I started with this:

```
with output as
(
    select id, name, position
    from   the_table
)
select array_to_json(array_agg(output order by output.position))
from   output
```

Now the output is as following:

```
[
    {"id": 443, "name": "first", "position": 1},
    {"id": 645, "name": "second", "position": 2}
]
```

But I don't want the `position` field in the output.

I am facing a chicken-egg problem: I need the `position` column to be able to order on it, but I also don't want the `position` column, as I don't want it in the result output.

How can I fix this?

I don't think the following query is correct, as table ordering is (theoretically) not preserved between queries:

```
with output as
(
    select   id, name
    from     the_table
    order by position
)
select array_to_json(array_agg(output))
from   output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways (at least):

Build JSON object:

```
with t(x,y) as (values(1,1),(2,2))
select json_agg(json_build_object('x',t.x) order by t.y) from t;
```

Or delete unnecessary key:

```
with t(x,y) as (values(1,1),(2,2))
select json_agg((to_jsonb(t)-'y')::json order by t.y) from t;
```

Note that in the second case you need some type casts because `-` operator defined only for `JSONB` type.

Also note that I used direct JSON aggregation `json_agg()` instead of pair `array_to_json(array_agg())`

Comment: That's nice, thank you. Can the projection also be done with just a SQL query and apply `json_agg` afterwards?

Comment: @CarolineKwerts `with t(x,y) as (values(1,1),(2,2)) select json_agg(t) from t;` ?